# Display a single blog post

Tags: php, mysql, database, blogs

I am using PHP + MySql.

My goal is to be able to click on a blog post title and have the site link to a page that will display just that blog post (pretty much like any wordpress blog).

I have searched for the way to do this over and over and cannot find any information that shows me how to and I don't even know where to start.  IF someone could just point me in the right direction or to an article that will show me how to do this.

I am assuming that i need to us Jquery to create a variable that takes the ID but I really have no clue where to start.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but your question doesn't apply to the terms of this community. You have to present a code and your attempts to get a an answer from other users. And for the record, your question indicates that you really need to gain more experience about web programming.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I know I should post code but as I stated. I don't even know where to start with this. I'm not looking for anyone to do it for me, just trying to grasp where to start as I can't find anything on how to do this.  And for the record, the reason why I asked the question is so I can gain more experience with web programming. Thanks for the productive comment though.

Comment: And that's why I said you need to gain more experience. StackOverflow is not a place for start programming rather for solving programmatic problems. If you need help with web programming I can suggest http://w3schools.com.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just wait until tomorrow when Im not on a tablet and can post the code I do have. I wouldn't say I'm completely novice, just not advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the title in an anchor tag with the URL of the post as the value for the href attribute

```
<a href="http://www.blogURLHere.com"><h1>Title goes here</h1></a>
```

Comment: I wasn't referring to how to link the page, but how to generate that information from the database entry into its own page. Kind of like here on stack overflow. You have a list of questions waiting to be answered. When you click on a question you go to a new page that retrieves that single question and displays it. That's what I don't get. I don't know if I am being clear which is probably why I haven't found the info on how to acheive this.